# Swap Left Alt and Right Alt on Kinesis Keyboard (or Any Keyboard)

Tags: keyboard, vim, tmux, xkb, kinesis-advantage

Let me back up my problem a little bit for context. I am trying to use the same modifier-key-plus-letter combination between both vim and tmux so that, if I have a vim pane/whatever on one side and a tmux pane/window on the other I can switch between them. To solve the root of this problem, I found the wonderful https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator.

However, I am already using the windows key for awesomewm's modifier key, so I can't use that key (but that also means I need access to it).

Therefore, I would like to use the left Alt key for both vim and tmux; right alt is not possible because the characters it sends are more than 8 bits (because of unicode, at least according to something I read somewhere; regardless of the reason, it doesn't work).

My problem stems from the fact that, in the Windows configuration mode of the Kinesis keyboard, there is a Windows key and a *right* Alt key, but no left Alt, and in the non-Windows configuration both Alts are there, but there is no Windows key. Does anyone know how to get both the left Alt and the Windows key on a Kinesis (or, more generally, to swap left Alt and right Alt, maybe with xkb)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows key is mapped to the PrintScr key in the non-Windows PC mode, so I just used that mode.